# Making put/post from Tornado doesent work

Tags: http, tornado, dropbox-api

I am trying to make a `PUT` method (or `POST`) to DropBox api, but it doesent work, I get a `GET` instead?

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from tornado.httputil import HTTPHeaders
from tornado.httpclient import HTTPClient, HTTPRequest

url = "https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/sandbox/world.txt"

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        headers = HTTPHeaders({'Authorization': 'Bearer TOKEN_FOR_DROPBOX'})
        HTTPClient().fetch(
        HTTPRequest(url, 'PUT', body="hello there", headers=headers))

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Update: using `GET` makes an error: `HTTPError: HTTP 400: Bad Request`

Here is a new code:

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from tornado.httpclient import HTTPClient, HTTPRequest

url = "https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/sandbox/wor.txt"

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.set_header('Authorization', 'Bearer DROPBOX_TOKEN')
        self.set_header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')        
        HTTPClient().fetch(
        HTTPRequest(url, 'PUT', body="hello there"))

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

but get this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1415, in _execute
    result = yield result
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 870, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 215, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 230, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "C:\Users\Abdelouahab\Desktop\ttttt.py", line 14, in get
    HTTPRequest(url, 'PUT', body="hello there"))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\httpclient.py", line 102, in fetch
    self._async_client.fetch, request, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 445, in run_sync
    return future_cell[0].result()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado\concurrent.py", line 215, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
HTTPError: HTTP 401: Unauthorized
ERROR:tornado.access:500 GET / (::1) 806.00ms`

I tried using an HTTP request builder extension from Mozilla, and it worked, so I guess the problem is how to do it on Tornado?

Comment: The /files_put endpoint does not accept GET, only PUT and POST: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files_put Can you show the full error you're getting when using PUT or POST?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it seems that it missed the `content-type`

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from tornado.httputil import HTTPHeaders
from tornado.httpclient import HTTPClient, HTTPRequest
from tornado.gen import coroutine

url = "https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files_put/sandbox/wor.txt"

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    @coroutine    
    def get(self):
        headers = HTTPHeaders({'Authorization': 'Bearer DROPBOX_TOKEN', 'Content-Type':'text/plain'})
        HTTPClient().fetch(
        HTTPRequest(url, 'PUT', body="hello there", headers=headers))


application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```